# How to label axes as multiples of some constant "a"?

Tags: plotting

I want to label X and Y axes as multiples of some constant "a" like a,2a,3a etc.
How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
α = Pi/2;
β = 1/2;
Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, -1, 10}, 
 Ticks -> {
   Table[{n*α, Style[n "α", Red, Bold, FontSize -> 15]}, {n, -1, 6}],
   Table[{n*β, Style[n "β", Blue, Bold, FontSize -> 12]}, {n, -2, 2, 1}]
 }, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Darker@Green, Dashed]]
```

[image: ticks]

Ticks are not shown at the origin because of this: https://wolfram.com/xid/0mrac6-sxo0e

Answer (score 0):

Use Ticks.  In the code below the first set is for the x-axis, and the second, y-axis.  Note how I can use Style to change color, size, appearance, etc.

Not sure why if I specify a tick mark at origin such as {0,Style["t0",Purple,18} it's not shown on the plot.  Maybe someone can fix this.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Ticks -> {{{0.2, Style["t0", Purple, 18]}, {1, "t2"}, {2, 
     Style["t3", Red]}},
   {{1/4, Style["t5", Blue, 16]}, {1/2, 
     Style["t6", Black, Bold, 18]}}}]
```

[image]